# Change Badge icon when notified

Tags: android, ios, firebase, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin Forms and I manage to send notifications to my applications in both iOS and Android using Firebase. I want to change the Badge icon every time a notification arrives, with the application in the background. 
Similar to Twitter or Whatsapp.

How can I change the Badge of my application when my application is in the background?

Comment: Are you after a Badge Icon that shows the number of messages?

Comment: @jack_tux  yes,exactly that

Answer (score 0):

I used MessagingCenter in Xamarin before. It is a publisher and subscriber event that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

For Android I use ShortcutBadger https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

But it's up to the Phone's Launcher to decide if it will show the badge and for me it wont show on the Emulator but it does work on my phone.

As for iOS I haven't looked into this yet so if you find one please do tell.